# Close ColorBox iFrame after submit

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm using jQuery [`ColorBox`](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) to display a shopping cart item. When a user enters the quantity in the iFrame (opened with colorbox) and clicks on the submit button, I want the iFrame to be close and main window (parent) to be refreshed automatically.

I mean I want two things after submitting data on iFrame:

1. iFrame closes automatically.
2. Parent window getting refresh automatically.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use this on the parent window while opening iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chpic").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, 
        onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); } });
});
```

and this to close the iframe inside iframe page:

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

Comment: @nik is there anyway to pass a parameter to the onClosed method?

Comment: Sorry @Anthony for late reply, coming here in sc after long time. you can always call a function on parent window from your iframe like: window.parent.functionInParent('myData');
just before parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();

Answer (score 3):

After the form is submitted in Frame 1, you can use the following JavaScript to reload the parent frame:

```
window.parent.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: where i have to write this?n that i frame or on parent html?
and i think this is not working in jquery colorbox

Comment: I used this on a close button in a colorbox and it worked great: closed the iframe and reloaded the parent page.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form target="_top">
```

Answer (score 2):

**open jquery.colorbox.js
find these two pieces of code:**

```
$close.click(function () {
  publicMethod.close(); 
});


$overlay.click(function () {
  if (settings.overlayClose) {
    publicMethod.close();
  }
});
```

**replace with these - note the addition of  " window.location.reload();"**

```
$close.click(function () {
  publicMethod.close();
  window.location.reload();         
});


$overlay.click(function () {
  if (settings.overlayClose) {
    publicMethod.close();
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: modifying the raw source sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Give form tag like this:

```
<form target="_top">
```

then after submit:

```
response.redirect("your form")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply simulate a click on the close button, like this:

```
$("#cboxClose").click();
```

Comment: this is the only one working for me. very clever. the other solutions apparently are not valid because you can only close a colorbox with the same Javascript that opened it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drupal 7, you may need to use the following alternative:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
```

In D7, the $.fn seems to be replaced by the jQuery object.

I simply setup a menu callback which simply returned this:

```
return <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
  parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
  //--><!]]>
</script>
EOF;
```

Seemed to work fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on current page :

1. write the following code on parent page where colorbox is applied.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tu_iframe_800x600").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"100%", iframe:false 

     });
   });
   ```
2. and the following code on your current page where you want to close colorbox `parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();`

*Note: please replace `.tu_iframe_800x600` with your html class on which the colorbox is called...*

Comment: please edit your post and format the code to make it readable