# Jquery colorbox, close colorbox after form submitted

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Using colorbox:

```
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/
```

Im using this to open a window up using the iframe function in colorbox. In the popup window/iframe I have a form. What Im trying to achieve is when the form is submitted I want the colorbox window to close and the parent window to refresh. Can anyone help me with this? Here is the code Im using now, when I manually close the colorbox window the parent page refreshes, but how do I tell the page inside the colorbox popup to close colorbox?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".purchasepop").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true,
        onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); }});
        });
```

Comment: I think this will show you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009973/close-colorbox-iframe-after-submit

Comment: @Tim should of noted I tried this but received the error: parent.$ is undefined. I included the colorbox js file in the popup, I also have jquery loaded as well. I know colorbox itself works because the popup works just fine, just trying to use the close function via the parent gives me that error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok got it to work, was referencing the wrong "variable" as I am using noconflict to load jquery. This worked:

```
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
```

Comment: This will work too if you get an undefined function error. parent.jQuery('#cboxClose').click();

Comment: +1 for having reminding me the conflict with mootools used in parent window

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to close my the color box on my cancel button click event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
     });
});
```