# Close Colorbox on Form Submit

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I've read this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009973/close-colorbox-iframe-after-submit) and a few others but I need to do something just a bit different I think.

I want to submit the form to a "processing" page that redirects back to the parent page of the colorbox after processing.

So, I need the colorbox to close on submission with the form contents getting to the processing page.  What I have now is just closing the colorbox on click and the form contents are never getting to the processing page.

Here is the code that closes the colorbox:

```
<script>
function closebox() {
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
}
</script>
```

I'm calling this function in the form tag:

```
<form id="frm_product_search" method="post" action="processing.php" onclick="closebox()">
```

I've tried putting the function on the submit button as well with no luck.

How do I get the form contents to the processing.php page before the colorbox closes?  I see this all the time with login forms.

Thanks

Brett

Comment: That onclick you have on your form should probably be an onsubmit.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work.  Just closing the popup without anything else happening.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the form contents to the processing.php page before the colorbox closes?

Submit it via ajax, then use the ajax callback to close colorbox.

Comment: Jack, thanks for the response (and thanks for building colorbox).  I think I left out an important piece of information.  Based on the contents of the form submission, the processing page redirects to a couple of different pages. So I need the form submission to hit the processing page and then redirect accordingly.  I'm beginning to think this won't work without creating/passing variables (sessions or cookies). Even then though, I don't want to refresh the parent, I want to go to a new page.  Thanks again.